# Change specific array values(vowels) to Uppercase in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

The code works but i need an optimized way,in JavaScript,can i get some suggestions on this please!

```
//capitalize vowels in a string

 (function (string) {
     var str = string.split("");
     console.log(str);
     var name = [];
     for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
         //console.log(str[i]);
         if (str[i] == "a") {
             str[i] = "A";
         }
         if (str[i] == "e") {
             str[i] = "E";
         }
         if (str[i] == "i") {
             str[i] = "I";
         }
         if (str[i] == "o") {
             str[i] = "O";
         }
         if (str[i] == "u") {
             str[i] = "U"; 
         }
     }
     console.log(str);
     return str; })("Hello Jane")
```

Comment: I think this question should go to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

What about

```js
var result = (function(string) {
  return string.replace(/[aeiou]/g, function(char) {
    return char.toUpperCase();
  });
})("Hello Jane")

console.log(result)
```

---

Without the anonymous function

```
var string = "Hello Jane";
var result = string.replace(/[aeiou]/g, function (char) {
    return char.toUpperCase();
});

console.log(result)
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/4fmyg95h/)

---

Without using regex

```js
var map = {
  a: 'A',
  e: 'E',
  i: 'I',
  o: 'O',
  u: 'U'
}
var string = "Hello Jane";
var result = string.split('').map(function(char, i) {
  return map[char] || char;
}).join('');

console.log(result)
```

Comment: thank you, do you think there can be any other way also than using the regex?in Javascript